# Restrict google maps API marker to only one click per marker

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a simple map Phonegap app where you click the map, and a marker is added, and a popup form shows. This is working just fine, but I need to make sure each marker is clickable only once.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(clickMarker, 'click',

        function (e) {

            addLocations(this.getPosition()); // calls popup form
            /*   clickMarker.setOptions({
                clickable: false
            });*/

            clickMarker.setClickable(false);

        });
```

Is what I'm asking possible? If it is possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Phonegap, but this certainly seems correct according to this example:  http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_click_change.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, instead of set the clickable to false, try removing the event listener

```
clickMarker.addListener('click', //add the listener to your marker object directly
   function (e) {
        addLocations(this.getPosition()); // calls popup form
        // Do ever things you want to do before calling this
        // Removing the event, so we can just call once
        google.maps.event.clearListeners(clickMarker, "click"); // don't forget the 's'
});
```

Since you're working with phonegap, I strongly suggest you to use this plugin for google maps, it'll be easier :

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

-- Carlos :-)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `addListener` with `addListenerOnce`. This will ensure that your listener is called once.